# Compute the distribution of P-values (for all possible values of x)

Tags: r, p-value

I want to compute the distribution of P-values (for all possible values of x) for hypergeometric distribution in R.
I am using this function:

```
p.values <- phyper(q=x.range -1, m=m, n=n, k=k, lower.tail=FALSE)
```

But it is returning:

```
x.range object not found.
```

How to solve this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Make sure that the object `x.range` exists by defining it before you call `phyper()`. For example like this `x.range <- 1:20`. Also there seems to be a misplaced `-1`g in your code above. The line should read `p.values <- phyper(q=x.range,  m=m, n=n, k=k, lower.tail=FALSE)`

Comment: Thanks! I used -1 because. By default, the R function phyper computes the inclusive lower tail of the distribution: P(X ≤ x).
With the option “lower.tail=FALSE”, phyper() returns the exclusive upper tail P(X&gtx).
We want the *inclusive* upper tail : P-value = P(X≥x). For this, we can compute the exclusive upper tail of the value just below x. Indeed, since the distribution is discrete, P(X >x-1) = P(X ≥x).  Am I missing something?

Comment: I see, sounds good. In that case please only pay attention to the first part of my comment.

Comment: Thanks ! Now i understand . it solved my problem!!!